# How many disjoint subsets?

Tags: combinatorics

I have a question about combinatorics.
I have the following set:
$$M = \{ 1,2,...,n \}$$

How many disjoint subsets
$$A\subseteq M, \quad |A| = 2$$ 
are there? For the future, how do I approach questions like these?
Thanks in advance for your help

EDIT:
$n$ is even. I want to know how many ways there are to split $M$ into disjoint subsets of size $2$. If this is any help, I am trying to figure out how many permutations in $S_n$ exist, that are involutions as well as derangements. For $n$ odd there are none, that's what I've shown so far. For $n$ even, I can write the permutation in brackets of size two (I don't know how you call this way of writing a permutation down).
The order of the sets do not matter.

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. You you want to know how many subsets has a partition of $M$ if these subsets have two elements? If this is your question the answer is simple: $n/2$ (or its integer par if $n$ is odd).

Comment: Do you mean how many two element subsets are there of $M$, or how many ways to split $M$ into disjoint two element subsets?  If so, what happens if $n$ is odd?

Comment: Sorry that I was not clear. n is even. I want to know how many ways there are to split $M$ into disjoint subsets of size 2.
If this is any help, I am trying to figure out how many permutations in $S_{n}$ exist, that are involutions as well as derangemengts. For n odd there are none, that's what I've shown so far. For n even, I can write the permutation in brackets of size two (I don't know how you call this way of writing a permutation down).

Comment: @MaxDoc  You should edit your question to include the information you placed in your last comment, where it may be missed.  In particular, it is important that readers are aware that $n$ is supposed to be even.

Comment: Do you care about the order of the subsets in the partition?  (I think I know the answer from the context that you included, but you should be clear in the question.)  For $n=6$, is $\{ \{1,2\}, \{3,4\}, \{5,6\} \}$ counted as the same partition as $\{ \{1,2\}, \{5,6\}, \{3,4\} \}$?  In other words, are you interested in a *set* of sets of size $2$ or a *tuple* of sets of size $2$?

Comment: No the order doesn't matter, thanks for asking I forgot to add that.
So the two sets you posted should be the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $A_n$ be the number of ways of partitioning an $n$-element set $M$ into $2$-element subsets. Pick $x \in M$. There are $n - 1$ choices for the element that is going to belong to the same partition as $x$, and then the remaining $n - 2$ elements can be partitioned into $2$-element subsets in $A_{n - 2}$ ways. Clearly $A_1 = 0$ and $A_2 = 1$, so we have:

\begin{align}
A_n &= (n - 1)A_{n-2}\\
A_2 &= 1\\
A_1 &= 0
\end{align}

Hence $A_n = 0$ for odd $n$ and for even $n$ we have:

$$
A_{n} = 1 \cdot 3 \cdot \ldots \cdot n -1.
$$

Comment: Very nice solution.

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot.

Comment: shouldn't it be ".. there are $n$ choices to pick $x$, $n-1$ choices to pick $y$, divided by $2$ because a subset is ordered, thus $A_{n} = {n \choose 2} A_{n-2}$" ?

Comment: @GCab: no. Try it with $n = 4$, say.

Comment: @RobArthan: thanks, ok, I saw now that the subsets are supposed to be unordered. So my supposition is going to be divided by $n/2$, leaving infact $(n-1)$ as a factor.

Answer (score 2):

Since $n$ is even, say $n=2k$ for some integer $k$.  How many ways are there to pick a pair of these integers?
$$
\binom{2k}{2}
$$
How many ways are there to pick a pair from the remaining numbers?
$$
\binom{2k-2}{2}
$$
So, the number of *tuples* (order matters for now) of the form $(A_1, \dots, A_k)$, where each $\lvert A_i \rvert = 2$ is given by the [multinomial coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem#Multinomial_coefficients)
$$
\binom{2k}{\underbrace{2 \; 2 \; \cdots \; 2}_{k}} = \binom{2k}{2} \binom{2k-2}{2} \cdots \binom{2}{2} = \frac{(2k)!}{2! \; 2! \; \cdots \; 2!}.
$$

To get the number of *sets* of the form $\{ A_1, \dots, A_k \}$, where each $\lvert A_i \rvert = 2$, you measure the redundancy.  How many times did each size $k$ set get counted as a $k$-tuple?  The number of permutations of size $k$ is $k!$, so the number of involutive derangements is
$$
\frac{1}{k!} \binom{2k}{\underbrace{2 \; 2 \; \cdots \; 2}_{k}} = \frac{(2k)!}{k! \; (2!)^k}.
$$
Miraculously, this expression simplifies further!  Notice that the denominator is equivalent to the product of the first $k$ *even* numbers $2 \cdot 4 \cdots 2k$; hence your count is is just the product of the first $k$ *odd* numbers
$$
(2k - 1)!! = 1 \cdot 3 \cdots (2k - 1).
$$

Here are the first couple values in [this sequence](http://oeis.org/A001147):
\begin{array}{c|rrrrr}
k & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
\hline
(2k-1)!! & 1 & 3 & 15 & 105 & 945
\end{array}

Comment: Thanks for your effort, the answer was very informative.